# Integer always a Floating point number

Tags: google-apps-script

All numbers are changed to floats, with a `.0` concatenated to the end.

I have tried `parseInt`, `toFixed`, `round`, `floor` and every other obvious choice.

A simple example:

```
Logger.log(list.length);
```

the log shows float values of type "Number" with a value of `5.0` for the length.

Any attempt to add numbers results in the same

```
for (i in [1,2,3,4,5]) {
  count++;
  Logger.log(count);
}
```

The log still shows float values

I would expect `Array.length` to return an integer

Comment: Hi, just wanted to check if the issue was still affecting you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33774009/11581830) it explains how the [Number](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-ecmascript-language-types-number-type) data type works in JavaScript (Google Apps Scripts are based on JS). If you need to display just the number before the decimal point, I would suggest using `toString()` and then `substring()` to handle it as a String, this would look something like this:

```
var numStr = count.toString()
var toDisplay = numStr.substr(0,numStr.indexOf("."));
Logger.log(toDisplay);
```

Then to use it as a number again you could use `Number(toDisplay)` ([Documentation here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_number.asp))

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
function toInteger(val){
    val = parseInt(val);    // in case val is not an integer
    return val.toString()
}

function testToInteger(){
    let ar1 = [1, 2, 3.6, 4.713];
    
    Logger.log(ar1);    //  [1.0, 2.0, 3.6, 4.713]
    Logger.log(ar1.map(toInteger));    // [1, 2, 3, 4]
    Logger.log(ar1.map(toInteger)[3]);    // 4
    Logger.log(ar1.map(toInteger)[3] * 2);    // 8.0
    Logger.log(toInteger(ar1.map(toInteger)[3] * 2))    // 8
}
```